# Condense matrix of values into one column?

Tags: r, reshape, transformation

I have a dataset where I have unnecessarily duplicated column variables that I want to condense down. I wish the output wasn't so clumsy and I've already had to do some work to transform it and make it easier to manage. I'm familiar with basic R stuff but not an expert by any means so please be patient!

[image: my dataframe]

Each R(1-10) corresponds to a response rating for the question (q1-10). The questions are randomised in order for each trial for each participant, so the qnum doesn't refer to the same question every time. I want to condense the matrix of response ratings down so that there is a single column called 'response' which reflects the rating given by the participant for each qnum for each trialNumber, so I don't have unnecessarily repeated tokens! Essentially going down the diagonal and reshaping it into one column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use quite easily using the `dplyr` and `tidyr packages` as follows:

```
df %>%
    # convert the columns to rows
    gather(key="response", value="value", R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10) %>%
    # select only rows where the reponse corresponds to the question
    filter(qnum == substr(response, 2, numchar(response)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I'm getting this error: 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `question`.
✖ argument "stop" is missing, with no default
ℹ Input `question` is `substr(question, 2)`.

Comment: Also, this is conflating two of the columns - I still need the original 'question' column as it has the text of the randomised question the participant is answering!

Comment: Let me know if the updated answer returns what you want.

Comment: Amazing thanks so much - I think this has done it!